# jQuery and Transfer-Encoding chunked

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

How does a response with a Transfer-Encoding of chunked effect jQuery's $.ajax method? Will it wait until it receives the entire response before firing the success function?

Comment: Have you tried it and experienced a problem?

Answer (score 4):

> Will it wait until it receives the entire response before firing the success function?

Yes it will wait.

Comment: Are you sure, it waits till entire response is received? I doubt, because I have one url which responds me with transfer-encoding:chunked as header but when we try using ajax, it sends parser error for JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of your request. you can do that with plain XHR.

```
let x = new XMLHttpRequest()
    x.open("GET", "/GetChunkedData", false)
    x.onprogress = function () {
        console.log(x.responseText)
    }
    x.send();
```

make the ajax requests synchronous 'false' to make sure until it receives the entire response.
Of course,

> it will wait by default.